# lng and lat lines on google maps v3 in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting unwanted longitudinal at latitudinal grid lines turning up on my google maps v3 maps when viewed in chrome. They appear whether i turn the map styling off or not. Any ideas what could be causing this? something to do with the container styling?

Thanks

[image: Maps V3 lines in chrome]

Comment: Those are not lat and lon lines, they are tile edges. Do you have any border styles applied to <img> elements?

Comment: strage - no i havent. even with all custom styles taken out it still does it (we're using bootstrap with less). any ideas what i can try?

Comment: I can only suggest that you post a link to a live demo page, so that others can debug properly. (I don't like guessing in the dark) ;-)

Comment: Bootstrap has caused issues with css before.

Comment: Hi, have you found the cause to this after all? I'm having the same issue on chrome (not using Bootstrap, no border styles on img's either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that it is because of the browser's zoom not being set to 100% (cmd +/-) ... if the zoom was set to something other than 100% then the maps api would show these lines on chrome (on my machine).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced exactly the same problem, so I tried to dig into this issue.
I was using a local apache webserver to check my webpages, so I used to type

`http://localhost/path/to/the/page/with/the/map`

By trying to view my page with localhost as a domain, the problem went off. So I tried to reach my page by replacing localhost with my IP address and voila! The problem disappeared.

To try yourself the problem and the solution, you can simply copy and paste the first offical google maps guide's example and try to view it by addressing it both through localhost and your IP address

[offical google maps example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=it)

Hope it helps